# What permission are necessary to access Data Import Wizard?

Tags: custom-object, permissions, data-import-wizard

what permissions do I have to assign to user that he will be able use Data Import Wizard to import data to custom objects? I gave him "Modify All" for that object but still can't see the Data Import Wizard in setup.

Comment: Hey, I think this thread might help you: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000grmnAAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey follow this link:-

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_import_general_permissions.htm

Hope this helps you.