# enable a user to use the import wizard to upload custom object records?

Tags: upload, data-import-wizard, data-import

How can I enable a user to use the Data Import Wizard to upload records to a custom object?
Currently I have a user with Create permission on a custom object, the custom object has a Master detail relationship to a parent object and in turn that too has a MD rel./ to another object, the standard object: Account on which they have create permission too.
However, when I am logged in as the user they cannot find the Import Wizard from the Setup quick find menu.

Comment: I have a feeling that they need modify all data to be able to do this. Going to check that.

Comment: Do you check this? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78669/what-permission-are-necessary-to-access-data-import-wizard

Answer (score 1):

To import records, following permissions are required. Please check if below permissions are given:-

> To import custom object data via the Data Import Wizard:
>   “Import
>   Custom Objects” 
>    AND
>  “Edit” on the custom object

Reference: [What permissions do I need to import records?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_import_general_permissions.htm&type=0)